# How to set text overlapping background to be white while overflowing outside to be in different color?

Tags: css

I would like to overlap circle with a text. How can I make it so that text outside circle is blue while text color inside circle is pure white?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQvZPV

```
<svg class="box">
   <circle></circle>
</svg>
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>

h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 800;
  max-width: 200px;
  color: #2f78e1;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #2f78e1;
  z-index: -1;
  background-blend-mode: color-burn;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly elegant, and you have to be conscious of your margins and padding to make sure the `:after` element lines up with the base element - but you can then use `clip-path` and mess with the numbers based on your exact needs to get a polygon shape. For this example I just removed the margins from everything and did a 50% circle for the clip path.

There's probably a better solution, but this should at least get you started. Unfortunately, using blending modes will be tough to get true pure colors, so clip-path with a cloned or pseudo element is a decent bet:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: 800;
  max-width: 200px;
  color: #2f78e1;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

h1:after {
    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    clip-path: circle(50%);
    color: #fff;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

#box {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #2f78e1;
  z-index: -1;
  background-blend-mode: lighten;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg id="box">
       <circle></circle>
    </svg>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: you complety change his code .. and in this case what is the need of the circle svg ? remove it and add background to pseudo element

Comment: I used his code and resampled it to illustrate the few changes he'd have to make to use `clip-path` instead of `blend-mode` -  I highly doubt he's using lorem ipsum as-written, so it's more principal than anything.

Feel free to edit it using a more complex clip-path if you'd like.